# Reporting average marginal effects of a survey-weighted logit model with R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey

I'm working with survey data of a complex sample to estimate binary outcome models. I am trying to report average marginal effects of a logit model, which I estimated through `svyglm` of the *survey* package in R. However, I get the following error when I use `margins` from the package of the same name:

`margins(fit, design = lapop) %>% summary()`

`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': arguments imply differing number of rows: 6068, 6054`

Seems it is not the `summary` function, since the error pops up when executing the margins command with its arguments. I have tried to simply ignore the survey weights at all and shows me equal coefficients and AMEs but not standard errors. Obviously, I cannot present this work by ignoring the survey weights. So I guess what I really need is the standard errors.

I have been reading on the topic and have found no clear solution, I suspect it might have something to do with missing values of the X in the model, but as with any other linear model, R should be just working with complete cases.

I'm not sure if anybody knows anything about this, or if I should simply just report AMEs without standard errors (and thus without p-values). I have uploaded a MWE if anyone is interested, which can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvgWfAgB6CDJi_1tOp0KCBiqlyPnEg?e=29a638).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was happening with this: turns out it's some kind of mistake in the package's code. You can take a look at the specifics [here](https://github.com/leeper/margins/issues/124). The solution as of today is to install Tomasz Żółtak's forks of the *prediction* and *margins* packages until his pull requests on Github are merged.

```
devtools::install_github("tzoltak/prediction")
devtools::install_github("tzoltak/margins")
```

This must be done after installing the *devtools* package if you haven't already.

```
install.packages('devtools')
```

After doing this, running `margins()` on a model should no longer produce errors if the model's dataframe has missing values on some or all of the model's covariates. Thus, it will present average partial effects with their corresponding survey-weighted standard errors. Check out a MWE [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvgWfAgB6CDJi_1tkFQVLi_nn_mOfw?e=QyDnY3).

Hopefully in the future calling *margins* directly from CRAN will be enough to not produce this error with survey-weighted models.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that there are `NA`s in some rows that R does not automatically exclude. First, I tried to reproduce the error message using both `fit` and `lapop` variables, and the error did pop up.

```
margins(fit, design = lapop)

#Error in data.frame(..., check.rows = FALSE, check.names = FALSE, fix.empty.names = FALSE,  : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 6068, 6054
```

Then, I tried to confirm which variable has the problematic `NA`s.

```
margins(fit)

#Note: Estimating marginal effects without survey weights. Specify 'design' to adjust for weighting.
#Error in data.frame(..., check.rows = FALSE, check.names = FALSE, fix.empty.names = FALSE,  : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 6068, 6054
```

The same error message popped up, so I believe `fit` contains the `NA`s. Then I checked how `fit` is produced in your code:

```
fit<-svyglm(ctol ~ y16 + age,
            design = lapop,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))
```

The `NA`s should have been in any of `ctol`, `y16`, or `age` columns. Then, I found `NA`s in `age`

```
> str(df46$age)

 dbl+lbl [1:3034] 30, 62, 25, 38, 24, 76, 39, 16, 71, 62, 29, 27, 60, 41, 22, 20, NA, 5...
 @ labels: Named num [1:4] NA 888 988 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Don't Know" "ns" "nr" "No sabe/No responde"
 @ label : chr "Age"
```

Then, I checked how many `NA`s are there in `age` column and where they are located.

```
which(is.na(df46$age))

[1]   17   28  802  888 1045 2401 2898
```

There are 7 `NA`s. I suspect this number relates to the numbers in the error message because there are 3034 rows in `df46`. Double the number, you get 6068. Double the number of `NA`s, you get 14, and 6068- 14 = 6054, the exact number shown in the error message.

Then, I tried to exclude the seven rows in `df46` to get the complete cases, and create the `lapop` and `fit` with the complete cases.

```
ind = which(is.na(df46$age))
df46_complete = df46[-ind,]
lapop<-svydesign(ids = ~ upm, 
                 strata = ~ estratopri, 
                 weights = ~ weight1500, 
                 nest = T,
                 data = df46_complete)
fit<-svyglm(ctol ~ y16 + age,
            design = lapop,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Finally, no error pops up when I run `margins()` :

```
margins(fit, design = lapop) %>% summary()

# factor     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
#    age -0.0026 0.0004 -6.0633 0.0000 -0.0035 -0.0018
#    y16  0.1323 0.0187  7.0638 0.0000  0.0962  0.1696
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I wanted to upvote but it won't let me, I'm pretty new in Stack Overflow. One question more, does this mean that for every model I run, I'll have to delete all missing values? This also seems to be only a problem with survey weights, not without. Thank you again!

Comment: You can check in options('na.action'). If it shows 'na.omit', then most probably you will need to omit the rows with missing values before you run 'glm' modeling. I have tried to change that 'na.omit' option to 'na.pass' and run your model, but this option resulted in another type of error. So, for your model, omitting NAs seems to be the only way to go.

Comment: I upvoted it for you, @DanielSanchéz. I do want to note that  the answer is incorrect in general, though ok in this case. The issue is missing data, but to get correct standard errors you should remove the missing observation *after* declaring the survey design, not *before*.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasLumley, however I found out that it is far more practical to use the amended version of the margins package (i.e my answer). I had been following the other answer so far, but it was very impractical to create new dataframes for each model. It didn't even cross my mind that the solution to this should work the other way around. Thank you!